# Is there any code inpector like sonarqube for flutter

Tags: flutter

Is there any code inspector like sonarqube for flutter.

As I am building a mobile app using flutter, I want my code quality very good. That's why I was searching sonarqube for flutter, but I was not able to find this.

Comment: As of now, SonarQube does not support Dart. Looks like you'll have to make do with the dart analyzer. Use `flutter analyze` in the terminal

Comment: The community of SonarQube is convincing them to support Dart/Flutter. You can follow the thread [here](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/support-for-dart/13555).

Comment: Thanks for the question, would love to know if there is an existing managed code inspector such as SonarCloud.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add analysis_options.yaml in the root of your project to enable extra checks and customize static analysis. You can read about it [here](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/analysis-options)

Answer (score 9):

I just released a Flutter / Dart plugin for SonarQube.
It is here : https://github.com/insideapp-oss/sonar-flutter

Comment: After implementing , main dashboard screen shows empty.No result found in dashboard. Have you saw any code smell or vulnerabilities.

Comment: I ever have a similar problem (no result found for code smell etc), and from the log, there is an error/warning that it could not find 'dartanalyzer', the file should be on flutter directory (e.g. flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin). So to solve it, make sure to add the directory on the PATH.

Answer (score 0):

hope you are doing good.

While working on Azure CI integration, I come to know that there is no official support for flutter/dart from official 'SONAR QUBE'.

It will be great if flutter/dart community/people/developer cast their votes here:

https://community.sonarsource.com/t/support-for-dart/13555